# How can I find out what RAID block size suits my needs?

Tags: raid

I'm building a RAID 6, 8 × 3 TB HDD, ext4 file system, mostly large files – 10GB or more (80%), 10-20MB (10%), 10% smaller files. The RAID contrloller is an Adaptec 6805.

How can I find out what block size I should use on my RAID controller to benefit the most?

Comment: If the files are going to be large, then I'd look at the largest block size supported by the file system.

Answer (score 0):

Benchmarking is usually the best way to determine the best performance for a given setup. You can start testing with 64k blocks, but I suspect you will get better performance at 256k or even 512k blocks. Build the filesystem with 4k (default on linux) blocks, but make sure those 10% of smaller files do not take up all available inodes.